# Visual Studio Deployment Project - Keep existing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I released a product to customers several weeks ago and now have an update.
I have database folder\files that are kept when the product is uninstalled.

Now when the the new version is installed it overwrites these files, Although I had set the properties: Permanment = true

Am I missing something?, or perhaps a condition needs to be created?
If so I havent done any and could do with some help please

Comment: It probably compares file dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Permanent property only ensures that the file doesn't get deleted during uninstall.  To prevent overwriting the file, you need to use the Condition property.  Get this started with View + Editor, Launch Conditions.  Right-click "Search Target Machine" and select Add File Search.  Set the Filename and Folder, note the property name (default "FILEEXISTS1").

Now go back to the file properties and set the Condition property to NOT FILEEXISTS1 so that the file only gets deployed when it doesn't already exist.  You can refine by date, if necessary.  Make sure you test this before sending it off to the customer.